# Connection to redis is timing out

Tags: redis

```
$ redis-cli -h ec2-75-101-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Could not connect to Redis at ec2-75-101-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379: Operation timed out
```

That's what I get from my host machine. I set up the Security Group on that machine to be open to port 6379.

When I run netstat on the redis server, I see that it's listening:

```
$ netstat -nlp
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
```

My `redis.conf` looks like:

```
daemonize yes
pidfile /var/run/redis.pid
port 6379
timeout 300
loglevel notice
logfile /var/log/redis.log
databases 16

save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
```

So why would I be timing out from another machine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

redis is only listening on the localhost port: `127.0.0.1:6379`.

You need to configure redis to bind on `0.0.0.0`.

in redis.conf (most likely at `/etc/redis/redis.conf`, replace (or add if not present)

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

with

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I changed it. Not sure if it changed anything though.

Comment: what's the new output of `netstat -nl`?  And you restarted redis, right?

Comment: Same issue as ops, this did not fix anything.

Comment: I tried this instead `bind 0.0.0.0   ::1` and that fixed it for me.